# Python Bokeh callback external python function

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I would like to call an external python function to get the callcack modification which I cannot using javascript math. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to call python functions directly from JavaScript callbacks. The JS callback code is executing in the browser, which is not the same process as a python interpreter. If you want to have user interactions, or tools, or callbacks that trigger real, actual python functions, you will have to use the Bokeh server (this is in fact what it is designed to do).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped. I was able to use bokeh server and get to execute external python functions.